# How to write dictionary to text, then read the text to dictionary in python

Tags: python, dictionary, file-io

My goal is to write a dictionary to text (so that I don't have to keep accessing a database), then save the information in the text file as a dictionary. This is what I tried:

To write the dictionary to text, I used

```
 with open("match_histories.txt", "w") as text_file:
    print("match_histories: {}".format(match_histories), file=text_file)
```

This seemed to work nicely and my text file looks like:

> match_histories: {'28718115': {'matches': [{'matchVersion': '5.13.0.329', ...

I want to save this as a dictionary, so I tried:

```
match_histories = {}
f=open('match_histories.txt', 'r')
match_histories= eval(f.read())
```

However, when I run it, I get an error in trying to save the new dictionary.  I get the following error

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "C:\Python34\Main.py", line 87, in
>
> main()
>
> File "C:\Python34\Main.py", line 82, in main
>
> new_dict = eval(f.read())
>
> File "", line 1

How should I save the information from my text file as a dictionary in Python?

Edit: Thanks to namooth, the problem was that my text file was not in a valid dictionary format. How can I not write the name of my dictionary to the file?

Edit 2: Wow, everyone is super helpful! I think I've got it now.

Edit 3: I tried the pickle dump that was suggested, but i got this error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "C:\Python34\Main.py", line 88, in
>
> main()
>
> File "C:\Python34\Main.py", line 79, in main
>
> match_histories=get_match_histories(challenger_Ids)
>
> File "C:\Python34\Main.py", line 47, in get_match_histories
>
> pickle.dump(match_histories, "match_histories.txt")
>
> TypeError: file must have a 'write' attribute

write:

```
pickle.dump(match_histories, "match_histories.txt")
```

read:

```
match_histories = pickle.load("match_histories.txt")
```

Do I still need a line opening the file? How do I fix this error?

Comment: What is the full Traceback you're getting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue with your current code is that you're adding a prefix `"match_histories: "` before the `repr` of your dictionary. Python can't parse that part of the text, so you get an error when you `eval` it.

Try just writing the `repr` of the dictionary by itself:

```
with open("match_histories.txt", "w") as text_file:
    print(repr(history), file=text_file)
```

This will work if all of the objects contained at any level in the dictionary have `repr`s that can be parsed back in properly. It won't work if the dictionary contains objects with unhelpful `repr`s, or if it contains recursive references.

A better approach is probably to use the `pickle` modules to save an load your data to a file:

```
pickle.dump(history, "match_histories.txt")
```

And later:

```
new_dict = pickle.load("match_histories.txt")
```

You could also use the `json` module if you want the text file to be human readable.

Answer (score 0):

The [json module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html) is perfect for me as [pickle](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html) produces barely readable content

Answer (score 0):

You should have a valid dictionary syntax in your text file. The following will work with your loading code:

`{'match_histories': {'28718115': {'matches': [{'matchVersion': '5.13.0.329', ...}`

Comment: Thanks! that worked.   match_histories was the variable name (in the code there I called it new_dict); perhaps that should not be included in the text file at all? So how should I change my "write" part to not include the name I used for the dictionary?

Comment: I would use `text_file.write(str(history))`, where history is your dictionary.